# I want to add tags like structure to my website

Tags: django

I have a field in my model where user enters it's skill. I want to show it like tags (as we do in stack overflow while posting questions)

I tried searching for it but couldn't find it, may be because I am not querying the correct thing.

Answer (score 0):

consider this model

```
from django.auth import get_user_model

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class UserTag(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'tag'),)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tags')
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='users')
```

to get / create a tag

```
tag = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name='django')
# applying it to user:
UserTag.objects.get_or_create(user=user, tag=tag)

# find user tags:
user.tags.all()

# find tag users:
tag.users.all()
```

Comment: this works if you only want to apply tags for user model, if you want a generic model that can tag any model, have a look at django's content type framework. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations